# Way to set dark mode for https://blender.stackexchange.com/?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to set the web interface to dark mode for https://blender.stackexchange.com/? I don't see that option in Edit Profile > Preferences. Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a dark theme for this site. Since we are using a "custom style", one would have to be handcrafted, I suppose

Comment: For questions about this site and how it works, please use https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: As far I am aware there is not, some info on main meta here: [Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: The only option available so far is to use custom style sheets via addons like Stylus or alike, there're even styles written specifically for SE to be used with addon. This is probably going to be the only option for a while